# I want to perform a login before users use my app

Tags: java, authentication

Hi, I was wondering if you could help me. I have a login form or frame rather on my application. It has username and password textfields and my application is connected to access database. I want users to login before the can perform other things on the application. In visual basic is a piece of cake but with java is a piece of rock this is the code that I have

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Login1 extends  JavaApplication1
{

    private static Connection conn;
    static Statement state;
    public static void login()
    {
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:Java_Testing";            
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("The driver was loaded successfully");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException error)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to load the driver" + error);
        }
        catch(SQLException error)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the database" + error);
        } 

        try
        {
            String query1 = "SELECT Username , User_Password From Users Where Username = ('"+ JavaApplication1.txtUsername.getText() + "' AND User_Password ='" + JavaApplication1.txtPassword.getText() + "')";
            state = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet results = state.executeQuery(query1);
            System.out.println("Congradulations you have succefully loged in");                     
        }   
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            System.out.print("Enable to login the user: " + error);
        }            
    }
}
```

`JavaApplication1` is just another class that is doing all the events handling and have the awt controls.

When I run this code this is the error that I get

```
Unenable to to login the user: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

If you have an answear please share and again look at the second try block, I know it's where the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to give your database login credentials in the URl

```
  String url = "jdbc:odbc:Java_Testing;user=dbusername;password=passwordfordb";
```

Comment: Thanks a million chaitanya.You have been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is incorrect. Your brackets are in the wrong place.

```
SELECT Username , User_Password From Users 
Where Username = ('txtUsername' AND User_Password ='txtPassword')
```

As you don't appear to need them, I would remove the brackets from the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your error i can say that there is a datatype mismatch which means that the datatype of the value you are passing doesn't match the datatype you have declared in the database.so just check in the database for the datatype.